# How to conditionally use a shortcode on WooCommerce single product pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, shortcode

How is it possible to hide a shortcode conditionally on WooCommerce single product pages if stock is empty?

For example if a product is out of stock:

- The shortcode `[scale-prices]` should disappear
- *(A green traffic light picture changes to a yellow traffic light picture)*

Comment: The rule on StackOverFlow is one question at the time… So your question needs more focus as it currently includes multiple questions in one. **It should focus on one problem only.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite broad. But you could add a CSS body class to the product page if a product (or a variation) is out of stock. You can then use that to manipulate your page for instance via CSS or JavaScript.

The following code snippet will add `out-of-stock` as a body class for a simple out of stock product, and a `{variation-id}-out-of-stock` body class for each variation that is out of stock:

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'add_class_if_product_is_out_of_stock', 10, 1 );
function add_class_if_product_is_out_of_stock( $classes ) {

    if ( is_product() ) {

        global $post;

        if ( $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID ) ) {
            if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
                $children = $product->get_children();
                foreach ( $children as $child_id ) {

                    if ( $product = wc_get_product( $child_id ) ) {
                        if ( $product->is_in_stock() == false ) {
                            $classes[] = sprintf( '%s-out-of-stock', $child_id );
                        }
                    }
                }
            } elseif ( $product->is_in_stock() == false ) {
                $classes[] = 'out-of-stock';
            }
        }

    }
    return $classes;
}
```

This snippet should be added to the functions.php of your child theme or via a plugin like Code Snippets.

Comment: Hello, thx a lot for your support!
I've implemented the code (appears in body class :-)) but had not time yet to manipulate
As soon I've done something I'll present...

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these single product page hooks and add a condition of your need.

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Like you can use `woocommerce_before_single_product` and check for product availablity and based on that result you can use `add_shortcode`, `remove_shortcode`. Also you can add script using `wp_footer` script if required.

You can share further details/scenario for exact solution.

Comment: for changing a price into e.g. a word I've found also the following code at website from our neighbor country (Austria):

https://kriesi.at/support/topic/woocommerce-hide-price-mark-sold-throughout-website/

add_filter( “woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html”, “theanand_remove_prices”, 10, 2 );
add_filter( “woocommerce_variable_price_html”, “theanand_remove_prices”, 10, 2 );
add_filter( “woocommerce_get_price_html”, “theanand_remove_prices”, 10, 2 );

function theanand_remove_prices( $price, $product ) {
if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()) {
$price = “”;
}
return $price;
}